# How to count cells in a row based on its value AND another cell in a different row's value?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google spreadsheet and I want to count the total number of cells where the value in Row 4 is "unpaid" and the value in row 3 is "walk*".  Please see the image below.

[image: my sheet]

I have tried a few things.  Looking at other questions has not been too helpful.  I thought that by using filter perhaps I would be on a good path, but it returns an error, and I can only assume I am not understanding how to use it correctly:

`=countif(filter(A3:G3, A4:G4="unpaid") "Walk*")`

I built this based off another answer I found where OP was trying to do the same thing I was, but with columns, not rows.  So I altered it for rows and it's not working.

I have also looked extensively at using something with

`=if(and(...)...)`

but they don't seem to be a good fit because I don't think they will return something I can count?

Something like if x is true and y is true then add one to z, but in lingo that sheets understands, I can't wrap my head around how to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try:

```
=countifs(A4:G4,"Unpaid",A3:G3,"Walk*")
```

Comment: Heh, that's it, so simple.  I appreciate it, nothing I was finding was directing me to countifs.  Everything I could find using "googlefu" was complicated or seemingly irrelevant.  Thanks a bunch for this learning moment.